# How to show heart sign in android using Html.fromHtml

Tags: java, android, unicode, special-characters

In my app I am fetching some data from the server, the data might contain some unicode characters like heart, etc.

Now I can show a black heart symbol using unicode format, this way

```
String str = "\u2764";//unicode character for black heart
TextView txtv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtv);
txtv.setText(txtv.getText()+str);
```

but I'm setting the text like this:

```
holder.txt_cardDesc.setText(Html.fromHtml(cardsDataClass.getCarddesc()));
```

> cardsDataClass.getCarddesc() returns "Ã¢ÂÂ¥All is changing soon, Christmas coming and we pray to God for all to..."

and I'm supposed to get 'Ã¢ÂÂ¥' as the heart symbol from the service.

how to show this special character in unicode format, or in heart symbol as it is required?

which format is this text showing?? Is it HTML/XML format or Klingonese character, I don't have any idea about this.

How to show the heart sign using Html.fromHtml in android?

---

EDIT: From the service I may get different special characters like " ' " or "&" but what I'm getting is "â€™" instead of " ' ", "Ã¢ÂÂ¥" instead of " ♥ "

Is there any way to check all the text and show the correct special character in android?

---

EDIT 2: Can anyone tell me how to show a heart symbol and apostrophe at their position from this string

```
String desc = "Ã¢ÂÂ¥heart icon check, Â€™ apostrophe check";
```

i have already used all these procedures:

```
byte[] bytes = desc.getBytes("UTF-8");              
String s2 = new String(bytes, "UTF-8"); // Charset with which bytes were encoded
txtv.setText(s2);

final String s2 = new String(desc.getBytes(), "UTF-8");
txtv.setText(s2);

String s2 = URLDecoder.decode(desc, "UTF-8");
txtv.setText(s2);

byte[] data = desc.getBytes("UTF-8");
String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
byte[] data1 = Base64.decode(base64, Base64.DEFAULT);
String text = new String(data1, "UTF-8");
txtv.setText(text);
```

but none of them are working, how to show UTF-8 text format in its actual format

Thanks

Comment: What is `cardsDataClass.getCarddesc()` returning?

Comment: this string: "Ã¢ÂÂ¥All is changing soon, Christmas coming and we pray to God for all to..."

Comment: What service? How are you consuming it? Either the service is returning mangled data, or you are implicitly decoding it with the wrong encoding.

Answer (score 1):

You maybe confused with Java Character & Android Character.

let your cardsDataClass.getCarddesc() returns:

"\u2764All is changing soon, Christmas coming and we pray to God for all to..."

and the heart should be shown just fine.

Comment: Sorry that string is coming from the service, I can't do anything about it, I'm asking about a workaround to show this text without changing what the service is sending, I really can't change the service

Comment: So ask the service what encoding the text are, maybe you are getting the ISO-8859-1 encoding text that do not contains the 'heart' character.